# Error: failed to retrieve rpm from base

Tags: installation, centos, package

I am trying to install a package on CentOS 5.7.

During the install when it was trying to resolve the dependencies it was downloading libxml2. But during that download it failed printing:

```
media://1315261980.416977%231/CentOS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.12.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 4] 
IOError: <urlopen error unknown url type: media>

Trying other mirror.
Error: failed to retrieve CentOS/libxml2-2.6.26-2.1.12.x86_64.rpm from base
```

As far as I understand its failing to download that rpm because of url problem. So, where  should I change the url. How to resolve this error ?

Comment: it's superuser.com / serverfault.com question

Comment: ok. sorry i just now posted there. thanks:)